# RhinoMocks: AssertWasCalled doesn't work on Stub

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, assert, rhino-mocks-3.5

I'm trying to assert with RhinoMocks that a certain property setter was called. But it's not working as expected.

The following simplified example illustrates the problem.

Consider this interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And now consider the following code:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyInterface>();
mock.SomeProperty = "abc";

mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SomeProperty = Arg<string>.Is.Anything);
```

I was expecting the assert on the last line would pass without problem. However, it is throwing an `ExpectationViolationException` with this message:

> "IMyInterface.set_SomeProperty(anything); Expected #1, Actual #0."

I can't understand why this should happen. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object returned by `GenerateStub<T>` doesn't record property and method calls. If you want to assert if setters, getters, or methods have been called, use `GenerateMock<T>` instead.

```
// Replace
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyInterface>();

// with
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyInterface>();

// and everything should work again.
```